# Serve static html files from a subdirectory in AWS Bitnami Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami

In a Bitnami WordPress Application, I want to add a subfolder and host some static HTML files there.
Actual website -- foo.com
Static HTML Site -- foo.com/staticsite

I created a sub-directory inside the /bitnami/wordpress/ folder but when I point to the domain it says 404 not found.

How can I configure such that static files from that folder are served?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I was uploading the folder in the wrong location.